# Format UserAgents

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I want to format my list of UserAgents in another type . This is what I want basically

```
Example:

This is the format : 


livebox/3.20.1 (build: 140119470; (Phone Model and Build) ; Android Version; en_US)
```

This is how my UserAgents look now:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; U20_Plus Build/NRD90M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Mobile Safari/537.36 [FB_IAB/FB4A;FBAV/263.0.0.46.121;]
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; W-V800-EEA Build/PPR1.180610.011; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/80.0.3987.119 Mobile Safari/537.36 [FB_IAB/FB4A;FBAV/263.0.0.46.121;]
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SM-A310F Build/NRD90M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/77.0.3865.73 Mobile Safari/537.36 [FB_IAB/FB4A;FBAV/263.0.0.46.121;]
```

All that I need from the list is (Android Version, Phone Model , Build)

And need to be replaced like this .

```
livebox/3.20.1 (build: 140119470; U20_Plus NRD90M; Android 7.0; en_US)
livebox/3.20.1 (build: 140119470; W-V800-EEA PPR1.180610.011; Android 9; en_US)
livebox/3.20.1 (build: 140119470; SM-A310F NRD90M; Android 7.0; en_US)
```

I have about 7 milions of it and I don't know how to replace it faster . I need a script or something . I know is not hard . Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

If you all your User Agents are "same", you can use this:

```js
var userAgents = [
  "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; U20_Plus Build/NRD90M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Mobile Safari/537.36 [FB_IAB/FB4A;FBAV/263.0.0.46.121;]",
  "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; W-V800-EEA Build/PPR1.180610.011; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/80.0.3987.119 Mobile Safari/537.36 [FB_IAB/FB4A;FBAV/263.0.0.46.121;]",
  "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SM-A310F Build/NRD90M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/77.0.3865.73 Mobile Safari/537.36 [FB_IAB/FB4A;FBAV/263.0.0.46.121;]"
];

for(var userAgent of userAgents) {
  var match = userAgent.match(/Android (.*?); (.*?) Build\/(.*?);/);
  
  console.log(`livebox/3.20.1 (build: 140119470; ${match[2]} ${match[3]}; Android ${match[1]}; en_US)`);
}
```